# Deleting SPAM answers

Tags: discussion, status-completed

When a an answer that is clearly SPAM, such as this one at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31281/4301, if the answer can not be removed all together, it would be preferable to actually delete the content and replace it with

> SPAM

I realize that there is actually very little spam here, and those with rep<10K won't see this, so this is not a big problem, nor even a problem for most users, but I don't see the point of actually leaving the content visible.

I saw that this was done on another question, so was going to edit this one but then saw that it is locked and I don't have that privilege so can't remove that content.

So, if there is not going to be a way to totally remove such answers, then it would be a good if those locking the question would remove the content before locking.

Hmmmmm.. Looks like this ended up being more of a rant then a question. So, the question (request) is: can some please remove the content of this locked answer.

Comment: Simply to keep things organised, I'm linking to a similar question that I asked about this a while back: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1437/etiquette-question-blanking-spam-posts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I removed the SPAM content. Of course it can be seen in the edit history though.